# SQL Retrieve First Matching row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a database which has two tables. A `Call_Info` table which holds details about incoming / outgoing calls and has a unique ID named `Call_ID`. I have a second table which is linked and called the `After_Call_Work` table.

Each call will have only one After Call Work Record. The dataset is a bit messed up and for the same call there are occasionaly 3 or 4 after call work records. How can I when doing queries just retrieve the earliest After Call Work Record for that particular call ignoring the rest? I imagined using SQL function First_Value but it doesn't seem to be the right one.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Any ideas?

Comment: Normally when you have a requirement such as `Each call will have only one After Call Work Record` there is a 1 to 1 relationship between CALL_INFO and AFTER_CALL_WORK:

           ALTER TABLE AFTER_CALL_WORK
           ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AFTER_CALL_WORK_CALL_INFO
           foreign key(AFTER_CALL_WORK.ID) references CALL_INFO(CALL_ID);  But that constraint was not in effect, as you  indicated, and there is a 1 to many relationship. The `earliest` after-call-work row would be determined by some date or datetime column in after-call-work that reflects its creation date. Is there such a column?

Comment: @Tim sorry I have not got back to you. There is a starttime column in the after call work table of when the after call work started and is held in seconds offset from 1970. It would have to be after the call ended though which is found in the call_info table. Still stuck with this

Comment: You should vote for our answers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by taking advantage of `Window Function`

```
WITH call_List
AS
(
    SELECT  Call_ID, OtherColumns, DateColumn,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Call_ID ORDER BY DateColumn ASC) rn
    FROM    After_Call_Work 
)
SELECT  a.*, b.OtherColumns, b.DateColumn
FROM    Call_Info a
        INNER JOIN call_List b
            ON a.Call_ID = b.Call_ID
WHERE   b.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bde84/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: Whats the `Window Function`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko bunch of window function can be found here [pgSQL Window Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) and also [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `select top`, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM call_info ci JOIN after_call_work acw ON ci.call_id=acw.call_id
ORDER BY acw.work_time DESC
WHERE ci.call_id=<your_call_id>
```

Comment: Note that this is valid if you're querying for one particular call id.  If you need to query across multiple calls and get the first match for each one, then use JW.'s solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH g AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY callid 
ORDER BY date ASC) AS row,* from after_call_work
select * from call_info cinfo inner join g on 
cinfo.callid = g.callid and g.row=1
```